# Make a scrollabe Gallery go to the top of image when Scrolled?

Tags: android, scroll, gallery, imageview

Hey, I have Pictures that are bigger than the screen in a gallery, so the gallery has scrollbars.. The problem is that if I go to the bottom of Picture1, and then scroll to go to Picture2, Picture2 stays viewed from the bottom... What I want is that when I go to Picture2, the gallery goes to the top of the Picture2...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Listener to get a call back whenever a new item is selected in your gallery:

```
gal.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                //Inside here you can call .scrollTo(0,0) on your ScrollView.
            }
};
```

Comment: onItemSelected will get a call back each time the user scrolls to a different item in the gallery. So if they are on pic1 and scroll the to the bottom then scroll the gallery right to pic2 onItemSelected is going to get a callback as soon as pic2 gets centered in the Gallery. The name is somewhat misleading it seems like this would be the call back for when an item is chosen(clicked on) But it is actually just when it takes focus (gets put in center due to user scrolling)

Comment: you are right, its gets called when the scrolling changes. Though mgallery.scrollTo(0,0) doesnt make the gallery go to the top!

Comment: Did you implement a vertical ScrollView yourself? or did it do it automatically? Try view.scrollTo(0,0); inside the onItemSelected(), that will try to scroll the child view that has become selected. That might be the one you need to scroll up for it to work.

Comment: Worked great, Thanks for your time/help and sorry for the many question I asked :)